# Measure noise in a binary bitmap line

Tags: graphics, graph, bitmap, computer-vision

I have a binarized bitmap with a set of edges (lines) similar to that shown on the following image

[image]

1. A smooth and straight segment.
2. A straight segment with high frequency noise, non-connected elements (floating pixels) and sometimes broken.
3. A smooth line with 2 important changes in orientation.
4. A segment with 2 important changes in orientation and high-frequency noise.

Those edges are boundaries of some regions on the image, I need to measure the quality of those edges (for segmentation purposes). This measurement should return 2 factors:

- High frequency noise
- Big changes in direction on a segment.

So, for the example above, the measurement should return:

1. Low high-frequency noise - 0 number of changes.
2. High high-frequency noise - 0 number of changes.
3. Low high-frequency noise - 2 number of changes.
4. High high-frequency noise - 2 number of changes.

For every given image, it is already known which pixels belong to each segment.
I don't have a graph of connected elements (pixels), just the bitmap. Trying to avoid creating one if possible.

**The algorithm should be fast, so speed is more important than accuracy (a reasonable approximation would be ok)**

What kind of approach could I use to perform this kind of measurements?

Comment: This question is really broad. Can you narrow it down?

Comment: I don't think it is, I just need to measure 2 parameters on an arbitrary bitmap edge :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an idea for the noise measure only.

I assume to have a bitmap image with just one segment, the image has `N` white pixels, the coordinate (row, column) of the `i`-th pixel is `(r[i],c[i])`, `i` goes from `1` to `N`.

Compute the height and width of the [bounding box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_rectangle) of the segment: the bounding box is a rectangle with sides parallel to the x,y frame; the bounding box has

```
width = c_max - c_min
```

and it has

```
height = r_max - r_min
```

where:

`c_min` is the minimum of `c[i]` for `i` that goes from `1` to `N`

`c_max` is the maximum of `c[i]` for `i` that goes from `1` to `N`

`r_min` is the minimum of `r[i]` for `i` that goes from `1` to `N`

`r_max` is the maximum of `r[i]` for `i` that goes from `1` to `N`

I expect that a line with no noise is composed by a number of pixels roughly equal to the length of the diagonal of the bounding box:

```
N_diagonal = sqrt( width*width + height*height )
```

now you have to compare `N` to `N_diagonal`: if `N/N_diagonal` is close to 1 the noise is low, the more `N/N_diagonal` is far from one, the higher the noise. If `N/N_diagonal` is very high you have a lot of white pixels compared to the minimum number of pixels needed to represent the line. On the other hand if `N/N_diagonal` is very low maybe the image has just some white pixels on it and no segment at all. So basically you need two thresholds that you can tune with some experiments with your available images; I would start with something like:

`N/N_diagonal < 0.95`: not enough pixels

`0.95 <= N/N_diagonal <= 1.05`: low noise

`1.05 < N/N_diagonal`: high noise

For the time performance of the algorithm: it seems to me the algorithm is O(`N`) for finding the width and height of the bounding box, and then you have some floating point operations in order to compute the diagonal and the noise measure.

If the diagonal approximation is not enough then you can get a better estimate with more effort, for example having a look at the [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).

Comment: I liked this approach, it's simple enough. Please note *N_diagonal* should be equal to the Manhattan distance between any 2 opposite corners on the bounding box IF the line is assumed to be 4-connected, and equal to the longest side of the box if the line is 8-connected.

Comment: @Xocoatzin Thank you for the info! Maybe you can put N_diagonal equal to the average of the Manhattan distance and the Chebyshev distance.